# Refresh page after the background script is done

Tags: php, http-headers, ob-start

I am using ob_  to do some background processing

```
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
header("Connection: close");
ignore_user_abort(true);
ob_start();
echo $buffer;
$size=ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush();
flush();
ob_end_clean();
file_get_contents($uri.'?loadchanges=1');
```

the script works fine but I need to refresh the page after

```
  file_get_contents($uri.'?loadchanges=1');
```

i tried

```
header( "refresh:0;" );
```

after or before

```
echo $buffer;
```

but it is refreshing twice and I am sure I dont need it there , I need it after the background process is finished.

any help is apreciated

Comment: that looks _very_ hacky to me. could you please explain what you are trying to do? i am almost sure that there are better alternatives for what you are seeking

Comment: I am recompiling LESS/CSS files if they have been changed, and it works fine , just need the refresh after the process is done

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what you want to do but using `Refresh:0` would result in continues loop you need to look for a way to make sure it does not refresh more than once also calling `flush` or `ob_flush` before calling header is not a good idea ;

Try

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);           //<-- Add to catch posible errors
ini_set("display_errors", "on");  //<------------^


if (!isset($_GET['refreshed'])) {
    header("Refresh: 0; URL=\"samplepage.php?refreshed=ok\"");
}
```